# Why does my flutter LineChart stop drawing in the middle of the chart?

Tags: flutter, dart, graph, charts

so I've been writing my first flutter app lately and at some point I wanted to display a LineChart with the charts_flutter package. Most of the time it works perfectly, but sometimes the graph doesn't stretch until the end of the chart. Sadly I wasn't able to reproduce that error precisely, but I guess it happens when you enter around 10 entries (?).
[That's how the graph looks when it doesn't work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3KGn.png)

I really hope that someone can help me because I'm out of ideas.

Here's my code for the chart:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final yTickFormatter = charts.BasicNumericTickFormatterSpec((num value) {
      return value.toStringAsFixed(2) + SettingsUtil.currency;
    });
    final customTickFormatter =
        charts.BasicNumericTickFormatterSpec((num value) {
      if (value == 0 && SettingsUtil.savingEntries.length > 1) {
        return SettingsUtil.savingEntries[1].getDateString();
      } else if (value == 0 && SettingsUtil.savingEntries.length <= 1) {
        return '';
      } else {
    return SettingsUtil.savingEntries[SettingsUtil.savingEntries.length - 1]
        .getDateString();
  }
});
return SizedBox(
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 20,
  height: 200,
  child: charts.LineChart(seriesList,
      animate: animate,
      primaryMeasureAxis: charts.NumericAxisSpec(
        tickProviderSpec: charts.BasicNumericTickProviderSpec(
            desiredMinTickCount: 2, desiredMaxTickCount: 3),
        renderSpec: charts.GridlineRendererSpec(

            // Tick and Label styling here.
            labelStyle: charts.TextStyleSpec(
                fontSize: 15, // size in Pts.
                color: SettingsUtil.getChartTextColor())),
        tickFormatterSpec: yTickFormatter,
      ),
      domainAxis: charts.NumericAxisSpec(
        renderSpec: charts.SmallTickRendererSpec(
            // Tick and Label styling here.
            labelStyle: charts.TextStyleSpec(
              lineHeight: 3,
                fontSize: 13, // size in Pts.
                color: SettingsUtil.getChartTextColor())),
        tickProviderSpec:
            charts.BasicNumericTickProviderSpec(desiredTickCount: 2),
        tickFormatterSpec: customTickFormatter,
      ),
      customSeriesRenderers: [
        charts.LineRendererConfig(
            // ID used to link series to this renderer.
            customRendererId: 'customArea',
            includeArea: true,
            stacked: true),
      ]),
);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `domainAxis` you need to set `desiredTickCount: seriesList.length`:

```
...
domainAxis: charts.NumericAxisSpec(
        tickProviderSpec:
            charts.BasicNumericTickProviderSpec(
              desiredTickCount: seriesList.length,
            ),
      ),
...
```